# Relationship between AgreementHeader table and PurchTable

Tags: sql, join, relationship, dynamics-ax-2012

In AX I have the PurchTable which holds purchases and in the AgreementHeader table which holds agreements. I need to tie together both tables in a join but can't see a link.

Can someone provide me with a join. I'm guessing it involves the vendaccount somewhere because each vendor purchases items and has multiple agreements in place.

Comment: Please make this a complete question by including sample data for both tables, your expected output, along with anything you might have already tried.

Comment: Did you take a look at the `Agreement` relation defined on the `PurchTable`? Did you take a look at [Relationship of Agreement tables](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/204121)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, could you chek in **PurchTable** the *Relation* `Agreement`

```
PurchTable.MatchingAgreement == AgreementHeader.RecId
```

Like this:

[image]

Good work.